# CMake 3.12+ findPython3 to include Python.h

Tags: python, c++, cmake, pybind11

I want to be able to create and run an executable file out of cpp class.
The class is including the Python header

```
#include Python.h
```

Right now i have the Path to the Python lib linked in the lib directory in VC.
However i want to be able to do it without that.
In the CMake file, i found python using

```
find_package(Python3 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Interpreter Development)
```

What do i have to do now? I tried out

```
target_link_libraries(executable_name Python3::Module aswell as Python3::Python)
```

Both methods didn't work and i got the Error fatal error python.h no such file or directory.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`target_include_directories(executable_name PRIVATE ${Python3_INCLUDE_DIRS})`

According to [CMake FindPython3](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPython3.html#result-variables), note that the variables names start with `Python3_` instead of `PYTHON3`.

Comment: Would be better to use `executable_name` like the asker used in their code example. Don't assume their target's name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the headers.

`target_include_directories(executable_name PRIVATE ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})`

Comment: Tried it out. However i found out, that there is another problem. Somehow CMake is unable to find Python and gives me an Error message when i set the find_package to REQUIRED.

`1> [CMake]   Could NOT find Python (missing: Python_EXECUTABLE Python_LIBRARIES
1> [CMake]   Python_INCLUDE_DIRS Interpreter Development Development.Module
1> [CMake]   Development.Embed)`

Also in the Error List i get this:
`Error LNK1104 cannot open file 'python38_d.lib'`

Comment: @Nova Have you installed Python?

Comment: I do. I also added it to the Path and am able to run commands. Tried it on my Laptop and i dont get the Error message. However, it still wasn't able to find the header file. Checking the Variable PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS I found out, that it's empty.

Comment: @Nova Have you tried `Python` instead of `Python3`?

Comment: Yes i have tried both Python and Python3